# blender-2.71-linux-glibc211-i686.tar.bz2 extraction errors

Tags: installation

Downloaded blender-2.71-linux-glibc211-i686.tar.bz2 for Debian use. Tried to extract the archive in (1) hard disk, but when failed with the following error codes, tried in (2) Pen Drive (or memory stick). The same error codes while extraction.

```
tar: blender-2.71-linux-glibc211-i686/lib/libGL.so: Cannot create symlink to `libGL.so.1': Operation not permitted

tar: blender-2.71-linux-glibc211-i686/lib/libGL.so.1: Cannot create symlink to `libGL.so.1.5.08005': Operation not permitted

tar: blender-2.71-linux-glibc211-i686/lib/libGLU.so.1: Cannot create symlink to `libGLU.so.1.3.08005': Operation not permitted

tar: blender-2.71-linux-glibc211-i686/lib/libGLU.so: Cannot create symlink to `libGLU.so.1': Operation not permitted

tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Later additions:

I had extracted as superuser. Still had the errors. That is why I posted it here. I tried both indirectly (writing nautilus -- browser /home/user/... and then using Archive Manager) and directly (typing the usual code in a terminal) as a superuser. Both neither helped. Have the same error codes:

```
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

The issue also surprises me, as I am receiving the "Cannot create symlink" and "Operation not permitted" errors. That made me think the issue is not for Unix (or Linux) forum but Blender forum, i.e., there might be an error in the Blender compressed file itself.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about extracting tar files in linux, not blender.

Comment: The tar download from blender.org works fine for me on Archlinux.

Comment: I have tried in both my Debian and Knoppix setup, and the archive has failed in both. Can't figure out why. @gandalf3

Comment: You can only create symbolic links across filesystems. Try extracting into the same filesystem as libGL, then move the blender folder to the memstick.

Comment: fat filesystem often used on thumbdrives doesn't support symlinks, closing.

Comment: > ... doesn't support symlinks, closing...  
From where did you **quote** this, particularly, the 'closing' part? Yes, true, it doesn't. When I tried to copy the extracted folder to the thumbdrive the same errors appeared, 'can not copy symlink'.  
Therefore, I am creating another ext2 partition in the drive and then would copy the file there.  
Please reply to my query.

Comment: Yes, with an ext2 partition in the usb drive I copied the extraction from the filesystem to the pendrive without any problem. No symlink errors were given. Thank you. Please tell me how you knew this was the case.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have permission to extract the file:
**sudo tar xvjf blender-2.71-linux-glibc211-i686.tar.bz2**
and type your admin pass after that (assuming it's your system)

PS: gandalf is right, this would be a question that you could ask on [super user stack exchange](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: I'm not sure if this makes sense.. If the OP didn't have write permissions, wouldn't tar also throw errors like "cannot write regular file so and so, permission denied"? Why only symlinks? Maybe I'm wrong though..

Comment: yes, i think you are actually right, as it wouldn't even get the stage of throwing a 'operation not permitted' error. If he says it didn't work, I will take it off, not to confuse anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

fat filesystem often used on thumbdrives doesn't support symlinks

as it happens however, these files are only needed for `blender-softwaregl`.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I wish to know how did you come to know this? Your advice is the result of a deep understanding of the system. I have tried it from Knoppix folder `/home/knoppix/Downloads`, but still the errors remain. I will try it from my native debian and inform.